# Loading Bootstrap Lightbox on Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a wordpress site which has a modal overlay for a particular button.

I have the following code for the modal

**HTML**

```
<div class="lightbox" id="send-contact-det">
(Content here)
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery('.open-lightbox').click(function() {
  var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  jQuery('.overlay').fadeIn();
  jQuery(link).fadeIn();
  return false;
})

jQuery('.lightbox .close, .overlay').click(function() {
  jQuery('.overlay').fadeOut();
  jQuery('.lightbox').fadeOut();
})
jQuery('.lightbox').each(function() {
  var lW = $(this).outerWidth();
  var mrgL = lW / 2;
  var lH = $(this).outerHeight();
  var mrgT = lH / 2;
  jQuery(this).css({'margin-left': -mrgL, 'margin-top': -mrgT})
})
```

Now this works perfectly on all my pages, except on the Search Page - where the content is being loaded dynamically.

I have tried the .live() and .on() functions, but in vain. Have been at this for a few hours now.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How about a jsFiddle?

Comment: Not sure how I'd be able to replicate the dynamic content in a jsfiddle. 

As I said, the above code works perfectly on a regular page. The lightbox shows well enough. But only when the links to the lightbox are served inside of a dynamic content, the lightbox refuses to appear.

The console doesn't show any errors either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the following workaround. It is working right now.

If anyone has a better way, let me know.

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-lightbox', function()
{
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.overlay').fadeIn();
        jQuery(link).fadeIn();
        return false;
});

    $(' .lightbox .close, .overlay').click(function() {
        jQuery('.overlay').fadeOut();
        jQuery('.lightbox').fadeOut();
    })
   $('.lightbox').each(function() {
        var lW = jQuery(this).outerWidth();
        var mrgL = lW / 2;
        var lH = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
        var mrgT = lH / 2;
        jQuery(this).css({'margin-left': -mrgL, 'margin-top': -mrgT})
    })
```

Fixed it just perfect! :)